# Better way to write MySQL sub-query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my MySQL database: `allele` and `locus`. I want to know for a given locus how many alleles there are and of those how many have the status `Tentative`.  I currently have the following query with subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as alleleCount,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM allele 
      INNER JOIN locus ON allele.LocusID = locus.PrimKey
      WHERE Status = 'Tentative'
      AND locus.ID = 762
      ) as newAlleleCount
FROM allele
INNER JOIN locus ON allele.LocusID = locus.PrimKey
WHERE locus.ID = 762
```

but I feel there must be a better way to write this query.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Which table is `Status` in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUM()` using sum with condition will result in a boolean 1 or 0 so it will give you the count for your conditions

```
  SELECT locus.ID,COUNT(*) `all_alleles_per_locus`,
  SUM(Status = 'Tentative') `tentative_alleles_762`
  FROM allele 
  INNER JOIN locus ON allele.LocusID = locus.PrimKey
  GROUP BY locus.ID
```

Comment: @eggyal to show the count of alleles regardless of status for that particular locus

Comment: @eggyal sorry if not get your point correctly lets say if there are 3 alleles for the locus 762 then the second column sum(locus.id = 762) will result as 3 correct me if i am saying wrong, and my above query is for locuses two particular columns are for 762 locus to show the count

Comment: @eggyal now i get your point  `locus.ID = 762` in sum is of no use updating my post thanks for a good point [this is the simpler one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe871/2)

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to group the locus by its statuses and fetch each status's respective count; using the `WITH ROLLUP` [modifier](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-modifiers.html) will add a `NULL` status at the end representing the total:

```
SELECT   status, COUNT(*)
FROM     allele JOIN locus ON locus.PrimKey = allele.LocusID
WHERE    locus.ID = 762
GROUP BY status WITH ROLLUP
```

If you absolutely do not want a list of all statuses, you can instead `GROUP BY status = 'Tentative'` (optionally `WITH ROLLUP` if desired)—but it will not be sargable.